# WooCommerce custom product and category urls

Tags: wordpress, url-routing, woocommerce

I need to change the URL pattern for the WooCommerce products and categories.

I wish it could be like the following:

```
# lists all the category products
/%category_name% 

# show the product
/%category_name%/%product_name%
```

Is there any way of accomplishing that by changing permalink settings of WooCommerce or should I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to unfortunately.

I found that I had to do the following changes so the URLs would look like so.

`http://domain.com/cars/family/`

`http://domain.com/product/family/camero/`

**Permalink Settings**

For the Common Settings set it to **Post Name**

**Optional Settings**

Change **Product category base** to `cars`

**Product permalink base**

**Custom Base** `/product/%product_cat%`

The system needs to know the difference between a category and a product and setting it like so works so hopefully this helps

Comment: hi, i am looking for same thing. website.com/shop/parentcategory/category/product while i am getting follwing url now: website.com/shop/category/product . i don' t know how to display parent category name in url . how to do that? have you got the solution?

Comment: @JackTorris have you set the default Permalink Settings to Post Name?

Comment: i am using woocommerce. woocommerce permalink setting i set  /shop/%product_cat%/ that is generating following url    http://mywebsite.com/shop/category_name/product name while i need http://mywbsite.com/parent-categoryname/categoryname/product name .  if product is assisgned to  multiple category it will generate following url: http://mywebsite.com/shop/category_name/product name .

Comment: forexample product is assisned to category a, categoryb and category c.if i open product through category B then url should be http://mywebsite.com/shop/categoryb/product_name  while current it is acception following url type: http://mywebsite.com/shop/categorya/product_name  it is displaying category name order base url. which is totaly wrong. if i have open product throguh category b the url should be http://mywebsite.com/shop/categoryb/productname  while i am getting http://mywebsite.com/shop/categorya/productname

Answer (score 0):

Its possible when you use a plugin. Although the plugin costs some money, but it will do the job fine. We are using it as well now since 1 month and it works great. See website here: https://perfectseourl.com